# ¿Cómo se cambia el texto de los botones de un Confirm Dialog de Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

Por default me están saliendo 3 opciones, la cantidad que necesito, pero las opciones me salen en ingles y quisiera poder mostrarlas en español...
Este es mi código:

```
int cambiarO = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Cambiar a:"); //Este es mi confirm dialog
if (cambiarO == 0) { //Opcion Si
    try {
        int cambiar = modelTabla.getSelectedRow();
        DefaultTableModel modelCambiar = (DefaultTableModel) modelTabla.getModel(); 
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt;
        preparedStmt = cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Auto set Reparado = 'Si' WHERE Placa = '" 
            + modelCambiar.getValueAt(cambiar, 0) + "'");
        preparedStmt.execute();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(registroAutos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
} else if (cambiarO == 1) { //Opcion no
    try {
        int cambiar = modelTabla.getSelectedRow();
        DefaultTableModel modelCambiar = (DefaultTableModel) modelTabla.getModel(); 
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt;
        preparedStmt = cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Auto set Reparado = 'No' WHERE Placa = '" 
            + modelCambiar.getValueAt(cambiar, 0) + "'");
        preparedStmt.execute();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(registroAutos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

[image: JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()]

Quisiera que en lugar de que diga Yes, No y Cancel estuviera en español o en cualquier caso poder poner el texto que yo quiera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo modificando los parámetros que recibe el método  `showOptionDialog()`

```java
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Mensaje ", //contenido de la ventana
                         "Pregunta" , //titulo de la ventana
                         JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, //para 3 botones si/no/cancel
                         JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, //tipo de ícono
                         null,    // null para icono por defecto.
                         new Object[] { "SO", "ESPAÑOL", "2020"},//objeto para las opciones
                         //null para YES, NO y CANCEL
                         "SO"); //selección predeterminada
```

La última línea permite que alguno de los 3 botones ya esté seleccionado por defecto cuando se abra la ventana, en este caso `SO`, el primer botón

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[FUENTE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#button

Mira en esta URL esta la forma de cambiarlos.

```
//Las Opciones
Object[] options = {"Si, Por favor",
                    "No Gracias!"};

int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
    "Would you like green eggs and ham?",
    "A Silly Question",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    null,     //do not use a custom Icon
    options,  //the titles of buttons
    options[0]); //default button title
```