# Como sacar adecuadamente los valores al pulsar el boton

Tags: java, java-swing

Comento lo que me esta pasando tengo que realizar un ejercicio que adivine un numero y el usuario vaya pulsando mayor, menor o acierto, el programa solo finaliza si el usuario pulsa acierto, entonces saca un mensaje diciendo has acertado!!

**Problema actual**

Al pulsar mayor o menor debería sacar números inferiores o superiores al que se muestra actualmente, mi programa hace esto en una pequeña medida ya que hay veces que solo muestra números aleatorios de forma que no hace lo que debería hacer el botón.

adjunto programa: (**edit**)

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Main {

    private JFrame frmAdivinaElNumero;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main window = new Main();
                    window.frmAdivinaElNumero.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Main() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmAdivinaElNumero = new JFrame();
        frmAdivinaElNumero.setTitle("Adivina el numero");
        frmAdivinaElNumero.setBounds(500, 300, 350, 130);
        frmAdivinaElNumero.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmAdivinaElNumero.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 1);
        frmAdivinaElNumero.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Adivina mi numero");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(104, 27, 156, 14);
        frmAdivinaElNumero.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JButton btnAdivinaMiNumero = new JButton("Click");
        btnAdivinaMiNumero.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                adivinar();
            }
        });
        btnAdivinaMiNumero.setBounds(114, 52, 90, 23);
        frmAdivinaElNumero.getContentPane().add(btnAdivinaMiNumero);

        JLabel lblPiensaUnNumero = new JLabel("Piensa un numero del 1 al 100");
        lblPiensaUnNumero.setBounds(61, 12, 185, 14);
        frmAdivinaElNumero.getContentPane().add(lblPiensaUnNumero);
    }
    public void adivinar() {
        int msj = 0;
        int randomInt = (int)(100.0 * Math.random());

        msj =JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, randomInt, //contenido de la ventana
                "Seleciona una opcion" , //titulo de la ventana
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, //para 3 botones si/no/cancel
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, //tipo de ícono
                null,    // null para icono por defecto.
                new Object[] { "Mayor", "Menor", "Acierto"},//objeto para las opciones
                //null para YES, NO y CANCEL
                "Acierto"); //selección predeterminada

        //msj = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frmAdivinaElNumero,randomInt);

        //opcion mayor
        if (msj == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION && msj !=JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
           do {
                 randomInt =((randomInt+(int)(100.0 * Math.random()))/2);
                 //Actualizar msj
                msj =JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, randomInt, //contenido de la ventana
                        "Seleciona una opcion" , //titulo de la ventana
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, //para 3 botones si/no/cancel
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, //tipo de ícono
                        null,    // null para icono por defecto.
                        new Object[] { "Mayor", "Menor", "Acierto"},//objeto para las opciones
                        //null para YES, NO y CANCEL
                        "Acierto"); //selección predeterminada
           }while(msj != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
        }
        //Opcion menor
        if (msj == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION && msj !=JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
               do {
                    randomInt =((randomInt+(int)(randomInt * Math.random()))/2);
                     //Actualizar msj
                    msj =JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, randomInt, //contenido de la ventana
                            "Seleciona una opcion" , //titulo de la ventana
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, //para 3 botones si/no/cancel
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, //tipo de ícono
                            null,    // null para icono por defecto.
                            new Object[] { "Mayor", "Menor", "Acierto"},//objeto para las opciones
                            //null para YES, NO y CANCEL
                            "Acierto"); //selección predeterminada
               }while(msj != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
            }
        //opcion Acierto
        if (msj == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "He acertado tu numero!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Con respecto a las opciones personalizadas, ya fue resuelto en otro hilo. Mira este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/322122/c%C3%B3mo-se-cambia-el-texto-de-los-botones-de-un-confirm-dialog-de-java . Si tienes alguna duda, puedes formular otra pregunta con respecto a eso.

Comment: ostras lo acabo de leer disculpa voy a verlo muchisimas gracias!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > pero al pulsar la opción cancelar (que seria acierto) si anteriormente he pulsado si o no entra en un bucle infinito y tengo que forzar su cierre y no logro cerrarlo.

Te faltó actualizar la variable `msj` adentro de la condicional `if`, de lo contrario, nunca podrás saber cual opción eligió el usuario.

Así debería quedar:

```java
//opcion mayor
if (msj == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION && msj !=JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
{
   do 
   {
         randomInt =((randomInt+(int)(100.0 * Math.random()))/2);
         //Actualizar msj
         msj = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frmAdivinaElNumero,randomInt);
   }while(msj != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
}
```

Y así mismo haces con la opción "menor".

**Actualización:**

El problema radica en la forma como estás generando el número aleatorio:

```java
//Opción mayor
randomInt =((randomInt+(int)(100.0 * Math.random()))/2);
```

Asumamos que el número pensando por el usuario es el 70. Cuando la función `adivinar` se ejecute, se genera un número aleatorio, en la cual supondremos que es 50 (el valor que tendrá `randomInt`). Posteriormente, el usuario elegirá la opción mayor, porque `70 > 50`. Entonces tu código debería de generar un nuevo número entre 50 a 100 (porque es el máximo).

Evaluemos la expresión:

- `(int)(100.0 * Math.random())` Vamos a suponer que esta expresión devuelve el número 1.
- Luego el resultado de la expresión de arriba se le suma el contenido que tenga `randomInt` (acuérdese que tiene el valor `50`), dando como resultado un 51.
- Por último se lo divide por `2` y da como resultado `25`. Es decir, este número generado de forma aleatoria no está en el rango de 50 a 100. Si seguimos iterando una y otra vez, no tendremos el resultado esperado, ya que **nunca** nos acercaremos al número pensado por el usuario.

Cada condicional tiene su propio `do-while` y esto es un problema, ya que si la primera vez el usuario elige la opción `mayor`, ¿cómo ejecutarás el código que tienes en la opción `menor` si es que el usuario lo elige? No se podrá porque has puesto los bucles de forma separada cuando en realidad deberías de usar un único bucle `do-while` y detectar que cuando el usuario selecciona la opción `mayor` se genere un tipo de número aleatorio y así mismo para la opción `menor`.

El código para generar un número aleatorio entre un rango de números es simple:

```java
//El valor máximo no se incluye
((int)(Math.random() * (N-M))) + M
```

Básicamente esa es la fórmula. Si quiero generar un número entre 50 a 100. Entonces `N` (valor máximo) será igual a `100` y `M` (valor mínimo) será igual a `50`.

Ahora lo único que se debe hacer es reemplazar en la fórmula los valores:

```java
((int)(Math.random() * (100-50))) + 50
((int)(Math.random() * (50))) + 50
```

Entonces si esta expresión: `Math.random() * (50)` devuelve el número `49`, al sumarlo con el `50` dará `99`. Acuérdese que el código de arriba solo devolverá un número aleatorio en la cual no incluye el valor máximo. Si se lo quiere incluir, habría que sumar un `+1`, donde la fórmula quedaría así:

```java
((int)(Math.random() * (N-M +1))) + M
```

En fin , sabiendo esto, podríamos descifrar como podemos lograr que el programa pueda adivinar el número pensado por el usuario.

El código propuesto es el siguiente:

```java
    private void adivinar()
    {
        int op;
        int randomInt = (((int)(100.0 * Math.random())) + 1);
        int max = 100;
        int min = 1;
        do 
        {
            op = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, randomInt, "Seleciona una opcion" , JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[] { "Mayor", "Menor", "Acierto"}, "Acierto"); 
           //Opcion mayor
            if(op == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                min = randomInt;
        randomInt = ((int)(Math.random() * (max-randomInt))) + randomInt;
                System.out.println("[" + min + "-" + max + "]" + " = " + randomInt);
            }
            //Opcion menor
            else if(op == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
            {
                max = randomInt;
                randomInt = ((int)(Math.random() * (randomInt-min))) + min;
                System.out.println("[" + min + "-" + max + "]" + " = " + randomInt);
            }
        }while(op != JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "He acertado tu numero!!!!");
    }
```

Lo acabé de probar y da el siguiente resultado (aquí el número pensando por el usuario fue el `23`):

```java
[1-55] = 35
[1-35] = 20
[20-35] = 21
[21-35] = 25
[21-25] = 21
[21-25] = 21
[21-25] = 22
[22-25] = 24
[22-24] = 22
[22-24] = 23
```

Si te puedes dar cuenta el algoritmo va hallando un nuevo valor máximo o mínimo dependiendo si elige la opción menor o mayor. Ya que para lograr que el programa adivine el número, necesitas que el intervalo se vaya acercando al valor deseado (que en este caso es el `23`).

Comment: Una duda sabrías porque cuando le digo mayor me sale un numero aleatorio que no es mayor al anterior? Actualizo el código a como lo tengo ahora.

Comment: @azucarilla No entiendo cual es tu problema. Te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y **explicar** en detalle cual es el problema del código.

Comment: Listo pregunta editada

Comment: @azucarilla He actualizado mi respuesta. Espero te sirva!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tomarte la molestia en responderme! y en explicarme todo perfectamente ahora si lo entiendo! muchisimas gracias!!!

Comment: @azucarilla Gracias a ti por compartir este ejercicio en stackoverflow. Estuvo interesante.